# How do I implement in Java a priority queue of a Tuple that sorts using both fields with different types?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I have created a class called Thread with two fields: int index and long start_time, like this:

```
class Thread {
    public Thread(int index, long start_time) {
        this.index = index;
        this.start_time = start_time;
    }

    public int index;
    public long start_time;
}
```

After that I've created a Priority Queue of Threads like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Thread> worker = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

So, I'm going to feed this queue with n threads with numbers from 0 to n-1. They all start with 0 as start_time like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers;i++){
            worker.add(new Threads(i , 0));
}
```

And later I'll add jobs in time, so lets say the jobs are {4 , 3}; if the Pqueue has 2 elements (0,0) and (1,0) it will turn into (0,4) and (1,3) as poll() will pick 0 as priority (ascendant according to index) but next time poll() will pop (1,3) first because 3 is less than 4 (so it sorts ascendant by start_time but if they are equal, then it sorts ascendant by index).

I'm just learning data structures and working with Comparable and Comparator so this is the first time I have to use it but most examples dont mention Tuples or they just sort by one field. My idea of implementation was this:

```
class threadComparator implements Comparator<Thread> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Thread a, Thread b) {
        if (a.start_time==b.start_time){
            return a.index - b.index;
        }
        return a.start_time - b.start_time;
    }
}
```

According to my IDE, I cannot use **return a.start_time - b.start_time** (incompatible types required *int* found *long*)

I used [this page in CodeGeeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/) as example but that example doesn't use long types.

Finally, how should where should I include this threadComparator to apply this sort order in my Priority Queue? I assume is:

```
PriorityQueue<Thread> worker = new PriorityQueue<>(new threadComparator);
```

Would that be right? Should I implement the Comparator in the threadComparator class or just in the Thread class.
Please don't be mean, I've googled for it and searched here in SO but I cant find a similar example. Hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: I would advise against naming your class `Thread` if this is anything more than code used to learn ; while it's not technically incorrect, it would be easily confused with `java.lang.Thread` in larger pieces of code.

Comment: Yes, at first I tought it would be a forbidden name for a class because the use of Thread for multi threading (which I a bit far from) but since it allowed I used just for this exercise but I know I should use other classes names, I just couldn't think of an appropriate one an my exercise called them threads. I'll change it to Worker before commenting and archiving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much on the right path, but for your comparator, you have to return int values:

- a negative number if the left side is smaller
- 0 if they are equal
- a positive number if the right side is smaller

So just replace

```
return a.start_time - b.start_time;
```

by

```
if (a.start_time < b.start_time)
   return -1;
if (a.start_time > b.start_time)
   return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: A simple answer but clear enought to understand what was wrong and how to use Comparator in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The substraction of 2 `long` values is of type `long`, which is why you cannot return

```
a.start_time - b.start_time
```

Furthermore note that in case negative values are allowed,

```
a.index - b.index
```

and

```
a.start_time - b.start_time
```

could overflow and return invalid results.

It would be preferable to implement the `compare` like this:

```
public int compare(Thread a, Thread b) {
    int c = Long.compare(a.start_time, b.start_time);
    return c == 0
                  ? Integer.compare(a.index, b.index) // compare index, if start_time is the same
                  : c; // if start_times are different, use the result of comparing the 2 fields
}
```

In java 8 you could also construct a comparator like this:

```
Comparator<Thread> comparator = Comparator.comparingLong(thread -> thread.start_time)
                                          .thenComparingInt(thread -> thread.index);
```

Comment: I answer is good but I couldn't be able to understand your answer unless I've read the other one which explains in layman's terms. I still don't understand how { ? Integer.compare(a.index, b.index) } and {: c;} works and I haven't learned lambdas yet. I'll save your Java 8 construct for later practice.

Comment: @Nooblhu: This is a tenary expression (see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/176/operators/4431/ternary-operator#t=2016090109370832655) and a short form of writing `if (c == 0) { return Integer.compare(a.index, b.index); } else { return c; }` in this case.